# Add Java EE Security Roles dynamically without using deployment descriptor

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I'm developing a Java EE 6 application using Glassfish 3.1, B06.
To secure my app, i'm using a JDBCRealm and programmatic security. This works fine to check username and password. But when it comes to declaring security roles, i have a problem:

To use Security Roles in Java EE 6, i have to declare those roles both in the EJB deployment descriptor and in the Glassfish-specific deployment descriptor to link those roles (as explained in the [Java EE 6-tutorial](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7627/bncbb?l=en&a=view))
Only than i can use the method *isCallerInRole(String roleRef)* inside an EJB to check permissions.

This is not desirable for my application, as i want that its possible to add Security roles both dynamically and programmatically, without having to write XML files (and for example make it possible to define role names in a database).

I just debugged through the GF3-source code and saw the implementation of isCallerInRole in *com.sun.ejb.containers.EjbContextImpl*. There the container gets the roles out of the EJB descriptor:

```
public boolean isCallerInRole(String roleRef) {
  (...)
  EjbDescriptor ejbd = container.getEjbDescriptor();
  RoleReference rr = ejbd.getRoleReferenceByName(roleRef);
  (...)
}
```

I looked around and found out that if i could somehow get the EJB descriptor inside my application, i could add a role like this:

```
EjbDescriptor ejbd = //??? Can i use that descriptor inside my app, or is that "forbidden"?
RoleReference rr = new RoleReference("admin", "Admins are allowed to do everything");
ejbd.addRoleReference(rr);
```

Anyone did something like this, or got some thoughts about it? Is it possible to use the Ejb deployment descriptor inside my application? Or are there better approaches?

P.S. or should i use MBeans to add Roles? Found a quite related post [here](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=232893&tstart=0).

Comment: As an aside, I would encourage you to move up to a more recent build of GlassFish Server 3.1.  The team recently released build 22.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, we have some libraries that break at higher Glassfish versions, so we have to stick with 06 until several bugs in these libs are fixed

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following solution to add roles programmatically after login, which works at least on GlassFish 3.1.2 build 23.

```
import com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContext;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.PrincipalGroupFactory;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import org.glassfish.security.common.Group;

public class GlassFishUtils {
    public static void addGroupToCurrentUser(String groupName, String realmName) {
        Subject subject = SecurityContext.getCurrent().getSubject();
        Set<Principal> principals = subject.getPrincipals();
        Group group = PrincipalGroupFactory.getGroupInstance(groupName, realmName);
        if (!principals.contains(group))
            principals.add(group);
    }
}
```

You will need to add `security.jar` and `common-util.jar` from GlassFish to your project libraries.

And don't forget to create a `<security-role>` section in your web.xml for the roles you wish to add.

Note that I am using functionality which does not appear to be part of a published stable API, so there is no guarantee that this will keep working in future releases of GlassFish.

I got the information on how to add roles from the source code of `sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.commit()` of GlassFish.
If a future GlassFish release breaks my code, this function would be a good place to start in order to find out how to fix it.

Comment: Nice solution for one part of the problem. However, I still have to define the roles statically inside the web.xml. But I want to add roles dynamically without having to restart the Server. We ended up doing it a different way. Cannot remember in detail, but I think we replaced a big part of the Glassfish security mechanism with our own.

Comment: I agree with ifischer. The only real solution is not having to add anything statically. This should be added to the spec really. The forced declaration might seem to have been a good idea once, but in practice it's severely limiting and especially in Glassfish needlesly verbose.

Answer (score 3):

The Javadoc does mention this requirement explicitly:

```
   /**
    * Tests if the caller has a given role.
    *
    * @param roleName - The name of the security role. The role must be one of the security roles that
    * is defined in the deployment descriptor.
    * @return True if the caller has the specified role.
    */
   public boolean isCallerInRole(String roleName);
```

However, I found that at least with JBoss AS it's not required at all to declare those roles in advance. In our case, the principal roles are dynamically created in the system and assigned when the authentication takes place. It thus impossible to declare those upfront.

Yet, the isCallerInRole method works perfectly well.

I realize switching to JBoss AS is not a solution, but maybe this information is valuable to someone anyway.